# How can I use other gems test fixtures?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rubygems, minitest

I am making my gem that has some dependencies. The gem uses `jira-ruby`.
I want use fixtures of `jira-ruby` (https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/tree/master/spec/mock_responses)

Can I use the fixtures?

Comment: that isn't using fixtures - it's using rspec

Comment: @David I mean mock_response files, here: https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/tree/master/spec/mock_responses